# DiscordJS Argument Slice

Tags: discord.js

I want to make a image embed via arguments, but I can't set the Title of the embed.
But when I try to run the comand, it errors out and the embed won't appear

```
if(message.content.startsWith(prefix + "foto-annuncio"))
{

if(!message.member.hasPermission(["MANAGE_MESSAGES"]))
{
  /* error message pops out */
}
let argsresult;
let mChannel = message.mentions.channels.first()
message.delete()
argsresult = args.slice(1).join(" ")
let url = args.slice(1).join(" ");
let title = args.slice(2);
message.delete();
const embed = new Discord.RichEmbed ()
.setImage(url)
.setColor('#008000')
.setAuthor('Delta Logistics', 'https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/604963851561336832/665504827044003860/zoom_delta_6_discord.png')
.setTitle(title)   
mChannel.send(embed).catch(err => console.log(err));
message.channel.send("Done!");
}
```

Comment: You can't set an array as a title, you need a string

Answer (score 0):

As Giuuliopime said you can't set an array as a title, you prob meant to join the arguments:

```js
const title = args.slice(2).join(" ");
```

Comment: I tried, but it still errors out, like this
`DiscordAPIError: Invalid Form Body
embed.image.url: Not a well formed URL.
    at /root/delta-bot/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/rest/RequestHandlers/Sequential.js:85:15
    at /root/delta-bot/node_modules/snekfetch/src/index.js:215:21
    at runMicrotasks (<anonymous>)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5) {
  path: '/api/v7/channels/727511359000150128/messages',
  code: 50035,
  method: 'POST'
}`

Comment: Read the error. args.slice(1).join(" "); doesn't evaluate into an image url.